# Manipulator model bugging out

Tags: sdformat

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

This is a followup to the question here:

http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17153/manipulator-joint-constraints/

I can't seem to figure out how the fourth link causes problems depicted here, when spawning the model. If I try to fix the base of the model to the world, everything seems fine until I start moving the joint, then it just breaks again. can this be caused, again by inertia? Or is there some typo or something that I'm not seeing...

Here is the code:

https://pastebin.com/asvmHPG9

Here is the result when spawning model without fixing the base, with fixed base after moving a joint it looks the same.

[image: image description]

Is this a problem with a definition of link, joint, or both?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/17185/manipulator-model-bugging-out/) by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Apparently, the inertia values were still wrong, for joints 4 and 6, even though I checked my calculations a number of times, so I increased the order of magnitude on them by 1.

---

Originally posted by [Fiddle](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/3737/fiddle/) with karma: 35 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0